# How can i read in an element name from an XML document using a reader?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

For a college project i am reading an XML document using an XML reader. I have this code so far for reading in XML elements and getting their attribute values, but i also want to verify that the elements i am reading the attribute values from all have a similar name. For example, if the element name is not 'pos' then i dont want to read the attribute from it.
Heres my code:

```
 while(_reader.Read())
 {
   if (_reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
   {
     if(_reader.HasAttributes)
     {
       piecesOnBoard[indx] = _reader.GetAttribute("piece");
     }
   }
  indx++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the `Name` property of `XmlReader`

```
if(_reader.Name.Equals("pos"))
    DoSomething();
```

With your code:

```
while(_reader.Read())
 {
   if (_reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
   {
     if(_reader.HasAttributes && _reader.Name.Equals("pos"))
     {
       piecesOnBoard[indx] = _reader.GetAttribute("piece");
     }
   }
  indx++;
 }
```

Comment: okay thanks for the help. Also one thing i just wanted to verify is, after it runs the loop once, when it goes into the loop the second time will it automatically read the following element? Thanks

Comment: `XmlReader` is forward-only, every time you call the `Read()` method it will read the next xml node, so your `while` loop will read the entire xml file.
If you want to go back to the start of your xml file you have to set the position of the stream to the beginning with something like `stream.Position = 0;`. This will work only with streams, if you use `XmlTextReader` your only solution is to create a new instance of it.